# Load video on hover in craft cms

Tags: eager-loading, video

I have a slider in my craft website where images are showing as item. When I hover on image it will display none and video will play. There are lots of video files. So when i refresh the page then it is taking time for loading because of video files. Any idea how can i fetch video from server when hover on image ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
document.querySelectorAll('.my-video').forEach(video => {
  video.addEventListener("mouseenter", function () {
    video.play();
  })
  video.addEventListener("mouseleave", function () {
    video.pause();
  })
})
```

You also need to add lazy loading, you can go 2 ways, but firstly change video attribute "preload" to "none"(<video preload="none"...) and then

1. Load video on hover

   video.removeAttribute("preload")
2. Or make via [Intersection Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) (as soon as you scroll to the container with the video, it loads)

Comment: The first approach is satisfying my requirement. Thanks